# Preventing Race condition in saving images from Fabric.js using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fabricjs, race-condition

I have a form that contains input in the form of text, in the form there is also an image that can be drawn. After the user finishes filling out the form including drawing in the picture. I will save the image in a public folder with the name `id_rekam_medis` which is created randomly in the controller and form data in the database.

However, I have a problem, it seems that I have a race condition, where the image that I save in the public folder has an `id_rekam_medis` name that is different from the `id_rekam_medis` that the form data has in the database. I have tried to change the controller order to save the image and then submit the form. However, it doesn't work. Is there any other way to solve this condition?

This is my javascript script for submitting the form and save the images:

```
function saveCanvas() {
        var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/rekam_medis',
                data: {
                    canvasData: canvasData
                },
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    resolve(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // Attach a click event handler to the submit button
    $("#submitButton").on("click", function(event) {
        // Call saveCanvas() function
        saveCanvas().then(function(data) {
            // If the saveCanvas promise resolves, submit the form
            document.getElementById("form_rekam_medis").submit();
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle errors if needed
            console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        });
    });
```

And, this is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $ID_rekam_medis = Str::random(8);
        $ID_rekam_medis = 'RM-' . $ID_rekam_medis;

        if ($request->has('canvasData')) {
            $imageDataURL = $request->input('canvasData');
            $fileName = $ID_rekam_medis . '.png';

            $imageData = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $imageDataURL);

            $imageData = base64_decode($imageData);

            if ($imageData === false) {
                die('Base64 string could not be decoded.');
            }

            if (!is_dir(public_path('images/rekam_medis/')) || !is_writable(public_path('images/rekam_medis/'))) {
                die('The directory does not exist or is not writable.');
            }

            $result = file_put_contents(public_path('images/rekam_medis/') . $fileName, $imageData);

            if ($result === false) {
                die('The image could not be written.');
            }
        }

        $dokter = Dokter::where('ID_dokter', $request->ID_dokter)->first();
        $nama_dokter = $dokter->nama_dokter;
        $pasien = Pasien::where('ID_pasien', $request->ID_pasien)->first();
        $nama_pasien = $pasien->nama_pasien;

        $rekam_medis = new RekamMedis();
        $rekam_medis->ID_rekam_medis = $ID_rekam_medis;
        $rekam_medis->ID_pasien = $request->ID_pasien;
        $rekam_medis->nama_pasien = $nama_pasien;
        $rekam_medis->ID_dokter = $request->ID_dokter;
        $rekam_medis->nama_dokter = $nama_dokter;
        $rekam_medis->tanggal = $request->tanggal;
        $rekam_medis->jam = $request->jam;
        $rekam_medis->save();

        return redirect()->route('rekam_medis.index')->with('success', 'Rekam Medis berhasil ditambahkan');
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: there doesn't seem anything that might cause data race, you're just generating random string for `$ID_rekam_medis` for every request which you use both on file name and in NEW db record. data race only occurs when you are trying to mutate a variable or db record from different request or function call, which I cant see in your code, try logging the ``$ID_rekam_medis`` on different section with timestamp, from when you initiate it, when you use it as file name, before you use it on db, and after db `save()`